# Is there a way to play Killer Instinct v1.5d online?

Tags: mame, killer-instinct, kaillera

I've never had the opportunity to play this game in multiplayer online.

AFAIK, it takes an emulator (MAME) that includes Kaillera (MAME Plus Plus) to play roms online, and also this emulator has to be compatible with the game in order to make it work.

The game doesn't work with the latest MAME Plus Plus emulator (0.119).

Which version of MAME Plus Plus (that includes Kaillera) shall I download to play Killer Instinct online? Any alternatives that enables me to play this game online, are welcome.